# How to integrate Credit card swipe reader ID tech shuffle in native iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, swipe, credit-card

I want to add credit card swipe feature to my application. Please let me know if I have to do anything other than the following:

1. Swipe the card
2. Populate the fields on the view with the card info
3. Store that populated into database(I have an idea in this db part), which will be used for further process later.

Please help me how to start programming for this. I have card reader device. What do I need to do now?

I'm Using ID Tech Shuffle Device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please purchase the UniMag for swipe card reader from the bellow link

http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/141.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCWVhHCD-nQ it's video for Swipe card

You simply need to integrate this UniMag SDK and can easily swipe the card to Your iOS Device

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply, The link shows six different device , in that which device is best to use , And each have different SDK's. can i follow one SDK's for all the iPhone supported device.Please help clarify me in this.

Comment: Please check the link now I have change it! you can download data sheet and SDK also from here http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/141.html

Comment: @iDhaval what's the password to download the SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Side note: If you are reading and handling credit card data, you'll need to ensure that you're doing it in a PCI-compliant manner.  You can check out https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/ for more info about the requirements, but they can be quite onerous.

You might want to consider a solution like http://getcardflight.com that manages the encryption for you so that you don't have credit card data flowing through your app and db.